# Refreshing / updating raster tif file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, update, arcgis-9.2

I have a load of different georeferenced raster tif maps loaded into ArcGIS (9.2). If I update the content of one of these maps in a program outside of GIS, (i.e. photoshop or equivalent,) I want the most up to date map to show in ArcMap the next time I open it.

It's linking to the file in windows, and I want to refresh the link

Right now, I don't know how to do this without either removing the map from the GIS file and re-adding it, or navigating to the file in windows and deleting the .aux and .rrd files, which is annoying.

Is there a setting or an easy function I can use to do this?

I am just learning GIS, and have no Python experience as yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you edit your TIFF in photoshop or similar it may not write the georeference tags so it would be a good idea to use world file registration (.tfw).

Normally when you change a raster you must rebuild the pyramids, else not use pyramids, you don't have to especially if the images are small. To rebuild the pyramids use GDALaddO http://www.gdal.org/gdaladdo.html if you are afraid of python or [build pyramids geoprocessing tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m1000000).